# How to query a Binary type in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of mixed types and I want to query the index 2 from the array which is Buffer type but stored as a Binary type in MongoDB. How do I query the binary type? I know I can convert the Buffer to hex before storing it in the database and convert it back to buffer while reading it but is there any option to directly query the Binary type from the database.

This is what the data looks like in the database.

```
scriptPubKey:Object
   cmds:Array
      0:118
      1:169
      2:Binary('VhC5pxY2EAcvkTOtuRomILb2DMM=', 0)
      3:136
      4:172
```

I have tried to query the data like below but it does not return anything.

Option 1: Querying directly base64 value

```
await unspentSchema.find({ "scriptPubKey.cmds.2": "VhC5pxY2EAcvkTOtuRomILb2DMM="})
```

Option 2:

```
await unspentSchema.find({"scriptPubKey.cmds.2": Buffer.from(publicKeyHash,"base64")})
```

Comment: What happens with `await unspentSchema.find({"scriptPubKey.cmds.2": Buffer.from("VhC5pxY2EAcvkTOtuRomILb2DMM=", "base64")})`?

Comment: It returns an empty array

Comment: How about `await unspentSchema.find({"scriptPubKey.cmds": {"$all": [118, 169, 136, 172]}})`?

Comment: But, I want to query based on the 2nd index of the array.

Comment: True, but I don't understand why "Option 2" didn't work, so I'm wondering if your document is in the collection and has the `"scriptPubKey.cmds.2"` you are trying.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the document is in the collection.